# Big Data Analytics Choice of Technology

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, apache-pig

I am asked to asses possible chice of technology we need to use for the problem described below. Possible options are Hadoop, Hive, and Pig. I do not have much experience with either of those. If you could point out a good source to read. I google and find tons of references but it is hard to find a step by step explanation or comparison.

Here is the task I need to solve.

Users enter sentences into the system. Sentences are broken out by words and stored in Cassandra column family. Each row is a single word (key) and column names are the time stamp this record was entered with no column values.

I need to be able to query the database and extract N words that are taken from the following breakdown:

a_1% must be the top words from period T1 from now into the past
a_2% must be the top words from period T2 from now into the past
a_3% must be the top words from period T3 from now into the past

a_n% must be the top words from period T_n from now into the past

a_1+a_2+...a_n = 100%

and T1, T2, etc are arbitrary time intervals.

any suggestion for a choice of technology I should use for this task would be greatly appreciate. We are using Cassandra and we are quite familiar with it. Now we need to decide which analytical tool to put on top of it.

Links or specifics would be quite appreciated.

Comment: This question is not constructive. Stack Overflow is not a site for shopping lists, polls, or comparisons.

Comment: That being said, sampling according to a probability distribution can be done with prettymuch any database or distributed system that you'd care to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data partitioned ( by time intervals ) in HIVE, finding such 'top words combination' sentences could be achived by one query in HIVE. Also HIVEQL sytnax might help with additional analytic in future, especially for people who know SQL. Question is how to integrate Cassandra with Hadoop. I hope someone might say something about it. GL!

**EDITED**: There is nice chapter about intergarating [Cassandra and HIVE](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9781449326944/17dot-storage-handlers-and-nosql/cassandrastoragehandler_html).

Answer (score 0):

The term **Big Data** is not very much unknown for most of the tech guys albeit there is some sort of confusion about it in everyone's mind. If we explain the term from layman's point of view, then it means the large volume of structured as well as unstructured data. Now a very usual question will arise in our mind after knowing the definition of the term big data that how we can get this large amount of data? As an answer to this question, we can say that we usually produce data when we communicate with our friends or when we do some digital transactions or when we shop whenever we go online.

[What are the solutions Big Data is providing which seem to be impossible even a few years ago?](https://askopinion.com/what-is-big-data-a-super-easy-intro-for-everyone)

We already know that information, photographs, text, voice, and video data is the base of big data and big data is now involved in so many projects for helping the mankind.